# iPhone keeping location after running an app from Xcode with a Location Simulation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-location

Some times after running some app I developed where I enabled `Location Simulation` in the scheme, my iPhone keeps the location across all apps (e.g Maps, GMaps, Strava etc.).

I have to reboot my phone to disable that simulated location.

Any idea how I could avoid that problem when I'm not debugging my apps ?